# How to bulk upload pdf from Google Sheet, inserting links next to rows?

Tags: database, pdf, google-sheets, google-drive-api, data-science

I have a lot of pdfs generated from a google sheet (pulled keywords from google sheet to create personalized pdf) - I need to have a google drive link (view only) next to a row with relevant information used to create that specific pdf.

There is a tool called Dropspread but it only works with 1 link at a time (https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/dropspread/1038626361348)

Please help, I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Can you better describe what are you trying to do? Do you have the files in drive and need to get the url of them?

Comment: Nope, I just have pdfs on a computer. I'd like to bulk upload them, share them (view only), and put a link on the rows where the pdf link contains the Item name in it. Dropsread is a good reference but it could only work manually.

Comment: Then have you checked on using Drive API [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add files in bulk to Google Sheets with the FileDrop add-on https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/filedrop/223672111812.

You select the cells and add the files to the upload area, FileDrop will automatically upload the files in Drive and add them to the cells with a link. Adding one file at a time is free but adding files in bulk with the add-on is a paid feature.

A quick video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZasNAPkE9Q